# How to find children element's children element using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie to `python`. I want to use `BeautifulSoup` to get the post date in a forum. I tried many ways but unable to get the correct result.

Here is my problem:

```
<td class = by>
    <cite>...</cite>
    <em>
        <span>2015-11-13</span>
    </em>
    </td>
<td class = ...>...</td>
<td class = by>...</td>
    <cite>...</cite>
    <em><a>...</a></em>
    </td>
```

There are 2 classes with the same name "`by`" but I only want the date in the first with "`span`" tag.

Here is what I have tried but have no idea what's the problem:

```
cat=1
    for span in soup.findAll('span', {'class':"by"}):
        print (span.text)
```

Comment: Ummm... `soup.select('td.by > em > span')` or similar?

Comment: You should consider posting the code you already tried, in order for others to make suggestions.

Comment: @JonClements thanks, this works

Comment: @Borisu thanks for your suggestion, I have edit the question with the code I have tried.

Comment: your `span` does not have a class attribute but `td` does. Have posted as an answer below. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution could be to iterate over `<td>` of `class='by'` and find `<span>`.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
a="""<td class = by>
    <cite>...</cite>
    <em>
        <span>2015-11-13</span>
    </em>
    </td>
<td class = ...>...</td>
<td class = by>...</td>
    <cite>...</cite>
    <em><a>...</a></em>
    </td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all("td",{"class": "by"}):
    for i in item.find_all("span"):
        print(i.text) # 2015-11-13
```

A more straightforward approach is

```
soup.select('td.by > em > span')[0].text # 2015-11-13
```

If you are only concerned with the first occurrence then as suggested by @Jon Clements you can use

```
soup.select_one('td.by > em > span').text
```

Comment: @JonClements I just wanted to give a more generic solution as actual html text could be bigger if you know what I mean but thanks for the suggestion I will update the answer

Comment: Sure... if one can always specify criteria to select it and it's only ever the first element you want returned as your match, then `.select_one` just saves returning a list of other possible matching elements... not a biggie, but if you don't need 'em, then no point having 'em returned.